# Problems with PHP Request Taking 5+ Seconds in a VirtualBox VM

Tags: php, virtualbox

I just created a new VM using VirtualBox, Vagrant, and [PuPHPet.com](https://puphpet.com/) and when browsers attempt to download static files (js, html, and css files have all been tried) they download in less than 100 ms.  If I try a PHP file, it starts to load and then the loading indicator in Chrome spins for about five seconds and then the page finishes loading or it displays nothing (seems to depend on the size of the page).  I received the following from the network tab with a basic `phpinfo()` file.

[image: Chrome Network Tab]

I've tried different networks types (host-only and bridged) and other VMs in the same instance of VirtualBox don't have this problem so it must be a configuration error in the VM.  I looked in the Apache error_log and dmesg but there aren't any error messages that show up when this happens.

Does anyone have any idea on why this might be happening or what else to try to debug this?

I found this question already ([CentOS VirtualBox 5 second latency on http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751597/centos-virtualbox-5-second-latency-on-http-requests)) and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Hm, quick question: is xdebug installed, and does it try to set up a remote debugging connection?

Comment: @Wrikken Xdebug is installed but the xdebug.remote_autostart setting is set to off.

Comment: _and_ it isn't started by 'accident' either? No GET/POST/COOKIE/SESSION value that triggers a debug session? What happens if you disable `xdebug`  altogether?

Comment: I just uninstalled xdebug and it has the same problem.

Comment: Hm, if you use `$start = microtime(true);...rest of code ...; echo microtime(true)-$start;`, does it say PHP has indeed been busy that long, or is that relatively 'quick'?

Comment: Depending on the page it changes but it's always less than 500 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Try using NFS sharing rather than the default VirtualBox shared folders. Add something like the following to your Vagrantfile:

```
# Set NFS sharing
config.vm.share_folder("vagrant-root", "/vagrant", ".", :nfs => true)
```

You will also need a host only network:

```
config.vm.network :hostonly, "33.33.33.2"
```

NFS sharing is not as convenient as the default as you have to enter a sudo password when you run vagrant up, but VirtualBox shared folders can get very slow.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually on a Window 7 host so this isn't an option for me.